# How can I configure 2 way SMS on Pinpoint with Python boto3 SDK to receive incoming message?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-pinpoint

After having purchased a number, how can I configure 2 way SMS on Pinpoint with Python boto3 SDK? I'm unable to find an API to wire the number to a SNS topic to forward incoming SMS messages to a backend lambda.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The right api is *pinpoint-sms-voice-v2.update_phone_number*. The SNS ARN is assigned to *TwoWayChannelArn* argument of the method.